# Webpack failed to compile when importing sass sub-files

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

**Update**
I figured that using the color variables is causing this issue! when i moved my _colors.scss to styles.scss and assigned static color values i managed to get through this although it's not pretty.

=================================================

I'm working on angular-cli project and Webpack fails to compile when having certain sass files imported in styles.scss!

I have other sub-files and it's working well when i don't import those (_layout.scss and _color.scss).

Specifically after trial and error attempts two things here causing this error:
- The color variables being used among the two files
- the font "CaeciliaCom" import in the file

All sass sub-files are located under asset.

I get this error.

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":["**/src/main/ngapp/src/sass"]}!./src/styles.scss
Module parse failed: ***/src/main/ngapp/node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!/Users/moal4675/Projects/printtool-app/src/main/ngapp/node_modules/postcss-loader/index.js?{"ident":"postcss"}!***/src/main/ngapp/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":["***/src/main/ngapp/src/sass"]}!***/src/main/ngapp/src/styles.scss Unterminated string constant (6:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

anfular-cli.josn:

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../webapp/ng",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "sass"
        ]
      },
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      },
      "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "scss"
      }
    }
  ]
```

**styles.scss:**

```
@import "assets/sass/layout";
@import "assets/sass/colors";
@import "assets/sass/icons";
@import "assets/sass/marginsAndPadding";
@import "assets/sass/misc";
```

**_layout.scss:**

```
/* Color variables */
$main-color: #002e5f;
$alternative-color: rgba(0, 47, 95, 0.3);
$alternative-color2: rgba(0, 47, 95, 0.8);
$opposite-color: #FFFFFF;
```

**_color.scss:**

```
header, footer {
    background-color: $main-color;
    color: $opposite-color;

    #userInfoToggle {

        &.userInfoToggled {
            color: $main-color;
        }
    }

    #userInfoMenu {
        background-color: $opposite-color;
        color: $main-color;
    }

    .popover-title {
        color: $main-color;
    }
}

/* Links */

a, .link-color {
    color: $main-color;

    &:hover, &:active, &:focus {
        color: $alternative-color2;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you configured `webpack` to load `sass` file ?

Comment: How? I'm working on angular-cli project! Webpack config file is in the source code and i'd rather not do changes in it.

Comment: try to install `node-sass`  using command `npm install node-sass`

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh install the package only? if yes i still get same error!

Comment: I am getting the same error when updating to Angular 4.3 and angular cli 1.2.1

Comment: npm install --save-dev node-sass resolved the issue for me

Comment: I also have "stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [ "../node_modules" ] }, in my angular-cli.json .. hope this helps

Comment: What i found out that using the color variables is causing this problem! when i define them statically it works fine!!